# How do you determine the lift coefficient of a finite wing using the coefficient of an infinite one?

Tags: lift, airfoil

How assuming I know the lift coefficient of an airfoil/infinite wing, how do I then use this value to calculate the lift coefficient of a finite wing? Please quote your sources.

Many thanks,